# How to integrate PayPal with Sylius

Tags: php, sylius

How would I go about enabling PayPal as a payment method in Sylius? I'm kinda confused why there is both a SyliusPaymentsBundle and a SyliusOmnipayBundle. Should this work with only a small amount of configuration changing settings in the backend or at the moment does this require writing code to do it? There is very little documentation at the moment. So far I've just tried adding code from http://sylius.readthedocs.org/en/latest/bundles/SyliusOmnipayBundle/installation.html and hoping some settings magically showed up in the backend. I'll try to look at it a little more but any suggestions would be helpful. I did see that https://www.sommelier-prive.de/ seems to have integrated PayPal.

Answer (score 3):

I working on sylius payum integration see the PR: https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/pull/275. It shows how you could use payum bundle in sylius app. For now it have two examples. First one is paypal express checkout and the second credit card (stripe via omnipay). Everything should be working. Unfortunatly as you can see from PR it requires some code writing.

Please pay attention since it is concept everything could be changed every moment. Let me know if you have any suggestions or troubles with it.

Some links:

- [payum documentation](http://payum.org/doc#PayumBundle)
- [payum sandbox](http://sandbox.payum.forma-dev.com/)

**UPDATED**

The PR was merged so now payum is used by default as payment abstraction layer. Stripe and Paypal Express Checkout works out of the box (because they were used to test things). Other payments could be adopted with small part of configuration and  few lines of code.

Actually you would have to implement `CaptureOrderWithXXXAction` class. Check for exist ones.

Comment: Can you explain implementing the `CaptureOrderWithPaypalAction` or refer me to someplace with more info? I was assuming PayPal would show up as a payment gateway in the admin but I don't see it there. I found all the paypal details in parameters.yml

Comment: @OzzieOrca Here's the link to [CaptureOrderUsingExpressCheckoutAction](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/master/src/Sylius/Bundle/PayumBundle/Payum/Paypal/Action/CaptureOrderUsingExpressCheckoutAction.php) (just in case you haven't seen it). The action is about converting data from Order to the payment specific format and starting capture process itself. If you ae about configuring payment credentinals: Right now it is not possible. I opened an [RFC](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/issues/469). You can track progress there (or help?). You can enabled\disable payments only.

Comment: I added `sylius_payments: gateways: paypal_express_checkout: paypal_express_checkout` to `app/config/sylius.yml` and finally got the checkout process to finish but there was no redirect to PayPal and in the backend the payment state was Failed (which makes sense since it isn't configured right yet). It seems like all the pieces are in Sylius now but I have no idea how to configure it. Do I need to do something with `sylius_payum:` in `sylius.yml`? What else do I need to configure, enable, or implement to make basic checkout with PayPal Express Checkout work? Thanks!

Comment: > Do I need to do something with sylius_payum: in sylius.yml? 

No, It does not contain any configurations

Comment: In the [comment on issue](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/issues/562#issuecomment-28464434) I described all places which you have to configure. have you seen it?

Comment: That comment looks helpful. I'll try it at some point. And no I hadn't seen it before.